# elasticsearch search object with multi criteria

Tags: elasticsearch

Hello i have document like this

```
{
    "_index": "undp",
    "_type": "visit",
    "_id": "10403_1",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
        "visit_id": 1,
        "beneficiary_id": 10403,
        "answers": [{
                "person_id": "1",
                "question_id": "102",
                "sub_question_id": "0",
                "option_id": "0",
                "question_value": "Ahmad Al-Saheb",
                "question_type": "input",
                "is_beneficiary": "1"
            },
            {
                "person_id": "1",
                "question_id": "103",
                "sub_question_id": "0",
                "option_id": "1",
                "question_value": "1",
                "question_type": "option",
                "is_beneficiary": "1"
            },
            {
                "person_id": "1",
                "question_id": "104",
                "sub_question_id": "0",
                "option_id": "1",
                "question_value": "1",
                "question_type": "option",
                "is_beneficiary": "1"
            },
            {
                "person_id": "1",
                "question_id": "105",
                "sub_question_id": "0",
                "option_id": "0",
                "question_value": "32",
                "question_type": "input",
                "is_beneficiary": "1"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

how can i apply search  for multiple questions values with and condition

```
(answers.question_id = 103 and answers.question_value = 1)
and 
(answers.question_id = 104 and answers.question_value = 1)
```

and how to search multiple  questions values with or condition

```
(answers.question_id = 103 and answers.question_value = 1)
    or
 (answers.question_id = 104 and answers.question_value = 1)
```

so after search i will get this document

Answer (score 0):

You can use, [Bool Query DSL](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) to achieve this. 
In Bool query DSL, `must = AND, should = OR and must_not = NOT.`

For example:
Query for `(answers.question_id = 103 and answers.question_value = 1)` would be:

```
{
    "bool": {
        "must": [
            { "term": { "answers.question_id" : "103" }},
            { "term": { "answers.question_value" : "1"   }}
        ]
    }
}
```

Since, you have nested logical operators, you can use nested `bool` query dsl as below.

```
(answers.question_id = 103 and answers.question_value = 1)
and 
(answers.question_id = 104 and answers.question_value = 1)
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        { 
            "bool": {
                "should": [
                    { "term": { "answers.question_id" : "103" }},
                    { "term": { "answers.question_value" : "1"   }}
              ]
            }
        },
        { 
            "bool": {
                "should": [
                    { "term": { "answers.question_id" : "104" }},
                    { "term": { "answers.question_value" : "1"   }}
              ]
            }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}


(answers.question_id = 103 and answers.question_value = 1)
or 
(answers.question_id = 104 and answers.question_value = 1) 
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        { 
            "bool": {
                "should": [
                    { "term": { "answers.question_id" : "103" }},
                    { "term": { "answers.question_value" : "1"   }}
              ]
            }
        },
        { 
            "bool": {
                "should": [
                    { "term": { "answers.question_id" : "104" }},
                    { "term": { "answers.question_value" : "1"   }}
              ]
            }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```